# Maximum sum of non-adjacent values

Tags: algorithm

I've found a couple of solutions to this problem on the forum but none of them seem to help me. Mainly because I've found one solution, but have no idea how and why it works.

The problem states: For a given array of positive integers find the maximum sum of non-adjacent elements.

The problem also strictly states that the solution must be in linear time. Here's what I've found:

```
int max1 = 0 
int max2 = a[0];

int i;
for(i = 1; i<n; i++){
    int new_max1 = max(max2, max1);
    max2 = max1 + a[i];
    max1 = new_max1;
}
return max(max1, max2);
```

Could anyone help clarify this solution?

Comment: Did you try writing down with your pencil a toy example and see how the algorithm would perform in that case?

Comment: Yes I did, on multiple examples in fact. Still can't catch the pattern.

Comment: @koy First device a dynamic programming approach. I would have chosen a bottom up approach. This solution would have taken O(n) space,O(n) time. Then, I would have further optimized on space by maintaining 2 variables for current and next. Your code does the same but I would suggest you to not dictate yourself to learn this 1 single solution and rather device your own solution. If you could do that, you will understand this too.

Comment: @Koy Try this. Rename `max1` to `max_without_last_element` and `max2` to `max_with_last_element`. Once you have renamed the variables, see if you understand the program.

Answer (score 0):

This is a DynamicProgramming/recursive solution which basically looks at 2 scenarios at each position whether to include or to exclude a value.
As all values in the array are going to be positive this solution works.
This solution would not work if the array contains negative values.

```
arr = Array of numbers
af = function(currentIndex, cummulativeSum){
 if (currentIndex >= arr.length) return cummulativeSum

return Math.max(af(currentIndex+2,cummulativeSum+arr[currentIndex]), af(currentIndex+1, cummulativeSum))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think to these couples of problems:

**P1i**: Find the maximum sum of non-adjacent elements of `Array[0:i+1]` containing the i-th.
**P2i**: Find the maximum sum of non-adjacent elements of `Array[0:i+1]` not containing the i-th.

where `Array[i,j]` is the subset of `Array` spanning from the i-th to the (j-1)-th.

Think how you can solve the `{P1(i+1), P2(i+1)}` in terms of `{P1i, P2i}`.

You're done!

More explicitly:

The base case (i=0) is `{Array[0], i}`

Then for i=1 the solutions for `P11, P21` are `{(Array[1] + P10), P20}`

Then for i=2 the solutions for `P12, P22` are `{(Array[2] + P21), P11}`

Then for i=3 the solutions for `P13, P23` are `{(Array[3] + P22), P12}`

Then for i=4 the solutions for `P14, P24` are `{(Array[3] + P23), P13}`

...

The solution you are looking for is `max(P1(n-1), P2(n-1))`.

The code you posted is iterative. It can be easily re-written in recursive form. Have fun!